# Get Local Cities names using Google Map API

Tags: android, web-services, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

In my android app, I have to list all local cities names using my current location with Google Map API

Input

1. Current Co-ordinates
2. Current place Name.

Output

Local cities of current place.

Comment: Please post the steps you have tried first, SO is not a place to have people do your coding for you.

Answer (score 0):

You must collect the latitude and longitude first.
then you can user geocoder to get it. Like :-

```
Geocoder gcd = new Geocoder(context, Locale.getDefault());
List<Address> addresses = gcd.getFromLocation(lat, lng, 1);
if (addresses.size() > 0) 
    System.out.println(addresses.get(0).getLocality());
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this way

```
public  List<Address> getAddressListFromLatLong(double lat, double lng) {

        Geocoder geocoder = new Geocoder(this);

        List<Address> list = null;
        try {
            list = geocoder.getFromLocation(lat, lng, 20);

                    // 20 is no of address you want to fetch near by the given lat-long

            for (Address address : list) {
                System.out.println(address);
            }
        } catch (Throwable e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return list;
    }
```